# Secure distributed container system for docker

Tags: security, docker, distributed-computing

I want to know if exist a secure distributed container system for docker.
I want to deploy encrypted container from master server (Private) and executed into a worker public server (Unsafe).
Do you know solution able to do that ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: What exactly is an encapsulated container?

Comment: Encrypted container sorry, i just edited the post.

Comment: Still, I'm puzzled. What is this? Could you please provide a link where the concept is detailed?

Answer (score 0):

[Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) is a built-in docker orchestration framework for docker. Swarm allows you to run containers on different machines. By default, communication between the machines collaborating in a docker swarm is encrypted and secure.

Swarm has master nodes and worker node. Master nodes distribute containers to be executed on worker nodes. Therefore, your usecase can be handled by swarm.